# Convert unicode base notation to string in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a data in form of `2\u2070iPSC`.
which is actually `2⁰iPSC`. how do i convert `2\u2070iPSC` to 2⁰iPSC using python.

Answer (score 2):

As a unicode string the data already is `2⁰iPSC`. I think that you are concerned about its display.

The code point `\u2070` *is* `⁰`:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2070')
'SUPERSCRIPT ZERO'
```

If you are using Python 2 you need to prefix the string with `u` to indicate that the unicode escape sequences are to be interpreted:

```
>>> type('2\u2070iPSC')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u'2\u2070iPSC')    # note `u` prefix
<type 'unicode'>
```

In Python 3 strings are unicode by default, so the `u` prefix is not required:

```
>>> type('2\u2070iPSC')
<class 'str'>
```

To *display* the string you can simply print it:

```
>>> print(u'2\u2070iPSC')
2⁰iPSC
```

This works if the default encoding of your interpreter can represent `u'\u2070'`, e.g. UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `u` as prefix in order to set it as unicode string.

```
unicode_string = u'2\u2070iPSC'
print(unicode_string)
>> 2⁰iPSC
```